# How to set particular bits in a byte for BLE data transmission?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bit

I am working on a BLE app on Android OS. I have to write data on the BLE hardware through my app. I am confused with the type of the transmission data I have to send. Following is an image which shows the byte data I have to send. For each byte, it has a different structure. [image: Transmission data structure]

In the Byte_2 I can send 0-100 values, i.e. okay.

In Byte_3 the first 4 bits has single value then 4th & 5th bits have the different meaning.

And in Byte_4 data is in 2 equal parts.

I am not sure how can I create this kind of bytes & use it.

[image]

Comment: Use bitwise OR operation. For example for byte_3: 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x0F = 0x3F. That's equal to TypeA & TypeB & BLevel(16). It's same way how you using others flags in android, only thing you need to do is define your values.

Answer (score 1):

- bit 0 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x01 (00000001)
- bit 1 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x02 (00000010)
- bit 2 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x04 (00000100)
- bit 3 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x08 (00001000)
- bit 4 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x10 (00010000)
- bit 5 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x20 (00100000)
- bit 6 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x40 (01000000)
- bit 7 has 2 value: 0x00 (00000000) and 0x80 (10000000)

After understand this structure, you can use bitwise OR operation to combine multi parts to 1 byte.

Example with Byte_3:

- Type A = 1 (00100000 -> 0x20)
- Type B = 0 (00000000 -> 0x00)
- B level = 3 (00000011 -> 0x03)

=> Byte_3 = 0x20 | 0x00 | 0x03 = 0x23